# Fortify Software security center configuration tool

Tags: fortify

I am using HP Fortify software security center configuration tool for establishing connection to remote DB. I have verified credentials by following mean

1. By logging it on DB server
2. By logging in on remote DB server via local SQL Server instance

BUT when i use the same username and password with this utility it gives following error 
" Cannot connect to database: Login Failed for user 'domainname\username".

Following are details i am using 
DB Driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQL.ServerDriver
JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;
DB Type: SQL Server (I am using SQL SERVER 2012 and user is having admin user privileges).
Maximum idle connections: 50
Maximum active connections:100
Maximum wait (ms): 60000
Db connection properties:

Please suggest what should be done to figure this issue out and make a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys issue is sorted out, somehow the DB user was not having proper rights (However he was admin thats quite strange). I created a new user and given him Admin rights and it worked. Seemed old user is having some policy or restriction issues.